# CPU temperature issue but cpu core not full used

Tags: cpu, cpu-cores, cpu-temperature

I think I have a problem with my processor. I recently changed my I5-9400KF to an I7-12700KF (I also changed my motherboard to the LGA1700 socket).
But since I changed, my CPU temperature is very high at idle, ~90°c. So I downloaded several software to check the status of my CPU. And each CPU core is around 90°c BUT the CPU core utilization is less than 10%.
I don't understand what I missed. My ventirad is also well placed. I changed my thermal paste.
I don't know what to do about it. I'm trying to ask here before I call a professional.

Comment: Calling a professional might be the best idea.

Comment: The thermal properties of a 9th generation vs a 12th generation is pretty significant.

Comment: The 9400KF is a 65W processor while the 12700KF is a 125W processor. Are you sure your cooler is adequate for the processor?

Comment: My cooler is a BeQuiet Dark Rock TF2. It's supposed to dissipate 230W. What do you think about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These temperatures are not immediately cause for concern. Instead, the temperatures *under load* are a more useful indication of the performance of your CPU cooler.

The thermal design of intel processors has moved, to take advantage of thermal headroom whenever available in order to deliver better performance. For example, Intel's Turbo Boost technology.

**The [maximum temperature for the i7 12700kf is 100C](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/134594/intel-core-i712700k-processor-25m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz/specifications.html). As long as your system is staying under this while under load, there is no immediate cause for concern.**

However, an air CPU cooler is not optimal for these high-power chips, and [intel recommends using a water cooler](https://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/gaming/resources/cpu-cooler-liquid-cooling-vs-air-cooling.html) for maximum performance. Using  a water cooler can help to deliver better thermal headroom for these high heat output chips, which in turn can enable the intel thermal design to provide you with even greater sustained CPU performance.

You may like to [see this interview with an intel thermal engineer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h9TjJviotnI) for further insights.

Comment: An air cooler certainly is enough to cool a 12th-generation Intel processor.  There likely is a more nuance problem happening. ~90°c at idle is sort of high, this probably is an indication the case is to small, to handle the additional thermal loads of what is typically a very hot processor.